# Suddenly parse.com stopped delivering push notifications just for one section of my app

Tags: ios, notifications, parse-platform, push

I have two sections in my app where the user sends invitations via push notifications like friend request and meet in a certain location, everything has been working fine for months but suddenly this week the section where the user invites a friend to meet in a location stop delivering the push notifications, while the other section for friend request works fine, i didn't change any of the code, i have checked certificates and everything its fine since the app it does send and receives the push notifications.
The notifications are received by parse but not delivered to the device.

Here's the code for the working section:

```
PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
                    [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:self.user];

                    PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
                    [push setQuery:pushQuery];

                    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ Wants to be your friend",[PFUser currentUser][@"name"]], @"alert",
                                          @"Increment", @"badge",
                                          @"", @"sound", nil];

                    [push setData:data];
                    [push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

                        if(!error){
                            NSLog(@"Push sent");
                        }else{
                            NSLog(@"%@", error.userInfo);
                        }

                    }];
```

And here's the code for the not working section:

```
PFUser* currentUser = [PFUser currentUser];

    PFQuery *pushQuery = [PFInstallation query];
    [pushQuery whereKey:@"user" equalTo:self.friendsSelected];

    PFPush *push = [[PFPush alloc] init];
    [push setQuery:pushQuery];

    NSString* meetYaMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@: MeetYA! @%@ in %@",currentUser[@"name"], self.biz[@"name"], _buttonSelected.currentTitle];

    NSLog(@"MeetYa message: %@ - from_user: %@", meetYaMessage, currentUser.objectId);

    NSDictionary *data = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                          meetYaMessage,@"alert",
                          @"Increment", @"badge", @"", @"sound",
                          currentUser.objectId, @"from_user",
                          currentUser[@"name"],@"name",
                          @"meetYa",@"messageType",nil];

    [push setData:data];
    [push sendPushInBackgroundWithBlock:^(BOOL succeeded, NSError *error) {

        if(!error){
            NSLog(@"Push sent");
        }else{
            NSLog(@"%@", error.userInfo);
        }

    }];
```

i have no idea how to trace this bug since its to difficult to know if apple or parse delivered the push notifications or not.

Answer (score 0):

In iOS8 you have a “different” method for push registering:

**iOS8**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerUserNotificationSettings:[UIUserNotificationSettings settingsForTypes:(UIUserNotificationTypeSound | UIUserNotificationTypeAlert | UIUserNotificationTypeBadge) categories:ni
l]];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotifications];
```

**iOS7 and below…**

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes: (UIRemoteNotificationTypeNewsstandContentAvailability| UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];
```

Comment: Thans TonyMKenu but the problem was the array of friends i was passing.